# Grouping data in ranges in R by summing them

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

I have data like this :

```
      year   nb
1     1901  208
2     1902  200
3     1903  223
4     1904  215
5     1905  187
6     1906  214
```

And I want to specify levels, such that I can summarize the data this way :

```
      years   nb
1     1901-1910  2082
2     1911-1920  6200
```

I had a hard time doing this either with group, aggregate, or encode until then. I found a very ugly way of doing that, like that :

```
sum(DF$nb[DF$year> 1901 & DF$year <= 1910])
```

But I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Sorry if my question is too basic,
Xavier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to create a new variable for your bins with `cut` or `cut2` in package Hmisc.

```
dat <- data.frame(year = 1901:2000, value = runif(100))
dat <- transform(dat, bin = cut(year, 10))
```

I would then probably use `plyr` to do the group by summary:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "bin", summarize, totVal = sum(value))
```

The help page for `cut` should be illustrative in defining labels, what to do with edge cases (include / exclude min or max values), etc.

Comment: floor((year-1900)/10) will produce a factor to summarize over.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Chase. I hasn't seen transform and would have likely done it this (second) way:

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(year = 1901:2000, value = runif(100))
dat <- transform(dat, bin = cut(year, 10))

set.seed(1234)
dat2 <- data.frame(year = 1901:2000, value = runif(100))
dat2$bin <- cut(dat$year, 10)

identical(dat,dat2) # true
```

Following on from that I would look to:

```
dat2$bin <- cut(dat$year, 10, labels=F) # this gives you 1:10 as labels rather than the very messy 'intervals'
aggregate(value~bin, data=dat2, sum)

> aggregate(value~bin, data=dat2, sum)
   bin    value
1    1 4.892264
2    2 4.546337
3    3 4.165217
4    4 4.733585
5    5 5.136625
6    6 4.530420
7    7 3.616002
8    8 3.864675
9    9 4.936536
10  10 3.328065
```

Comment: check out `with` and `within` for cousins to `transform`. plyr adds `summarize` to the mix as well.